# What BPM tools are appropriate for Spring?

Tags: java, spring, business-process-management

Can jBPM and Drools works with Spring? Or any other BPM tools?
I have some very positive experience with Spring and I'd prefer checking BPM solutions with integration with Spring and not with jBoss, Seam or another full Java application server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have done a lot of POC on this and Activiti is my preference. Apart from other things like BPMN 2 support, Apache 2 License etc it has built-in module to work with Spring and also Spring is a [supporting partner](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/alfresco-springsource-launch-activiti-bpm-open-source-project/6511) of Activiti along with Alfresco.

Answer (score 1):

jBPM, Drools and Activiti are integrating easily with Spring. ...and probably every popular BPM solution on the market as well.